# Publisher's responses to wmode=direct?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, wmode, publisher

Not many portals supported wmode=direct or gpu a while ago. I suppose the things are now changing fast and many folks are making accelerated/Stage3D games. Since many portals are supporting wmode direct, it should not be difficult to look for a sponsor, or is it ?

What is your experience? Stage3D enabled game (say using starling) has roughly equal chances or getting a sponsor and will it get equally wider audience as compared to normal (non-accelerated) flash game?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, and ontop of that, it's extremely opinion based. From my experience, sponsors will pay more / be more likely to pay you for a game that they think is more likely to attract visitors to their website. The idea is that people visiting their website translates into ad impressions, which translates into them making their money back and beginning to profit.

Comment: Yes indeed I am asking for other peoples' opinions and experiences :)